# What is the lifecycle of vue apollo subscriptions?

Tags: vue.js, apollo, vue-apollo

Does `vue-apollo` automatically unsubscribe the query when the View changes?

For example, I have two views routed to `/users` and `/orders`. `/users` has a subscription to the `users` table and `/orders` has a subscription to the `orders` table.

If I were on the `/user` page, would the `order` subscription still be in effect? If yes, how would I be able to turn it off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Apollo queries are bound to your component they will follow the lifecycle of your components, i.e. if your route changes (different components are renderd), your old components will be deleted and therefore your old queries will also be removed.

This is taken care of within Vue apollo by [this mixin](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-apollo/blob/dev/packages/vue-apollo/src/mixin.js).

Take a look at the following part:

```
export function installMixin (Vue, vueVersion) {
  Vue.mixin({
    // Other irrelevant code for this question
    destroyed: destroy,
  })
}
```

This means it binds to the 'destroyed' event of each Vue component which will then trigger the destroy function (as defined by the [Vue API reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin)):

```
function destroy () {
  if (this.$_apollo) {
    this.$_apollo.destroy()
  }
}
```

So this process ensures your queries are destroyed and not in effect anymore when your component is destroyed.

I hope this answers your question

Comment: thanks! this is great. I appreciate the link to the code.